# Significado de "incidente de ejecución"

Tags: significado, lenguaje-jurídico

¿Qué significa esta expresión? ¿Hay una frase sinónima que se entienda (para traducirla al inglés!)?

Comment: puedes poner la frase de dónde lo has sacado?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir algo de contexto? ¿Dónde has visto esa expresión? Con una búsqueda rápida en Google, da la impresión de que es un término legal especializado. Quizás va más allá de la función de este sitio determinar cuál es el término equivalente en un sistema de justicia anglosajón

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Michael! (o benvingut, que crec que xerres català!). Como te indicaron otros usuarios, sería útil que proporcionaras el contexto donde encontraste esta expresión, que parece jurídica. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 2):

> ### Diccionario del español jurídico | RAE
>
> #### [incidente de ejecución de sentencia](https://dej.rae.es/lema/incidente-de-ejecuci%C3%B3n-de-sentencia)
>
> Sublema de [incidente<sup>1</sup>](https://dej.rae.es/lema/incidente1)
>
> > *Gral.* Cauce procesal destinado a resolver los problemas que puede conllevar el cumplimiento de la sentencia en sus justos términos.
> >
> > - De este modo ha de quedar establecido de modo meridiano que el incidente de ejecución de sentencia no es una continuación del pleito principal, pues su objeto está dirigido a hacer cumplir el fallo definitivo dictado. Es decir, a comprobar que la ejecución de la sentencia no es "mas", "menos" o "distinto" de lo resuelto, decidido, en el proceso declarativo
> >
> >   > [ejecución](https://dej.rae.es/lema/ejecuci%C3%B3n)

Answer (score 2):

Context is important because "ejecución" in Spanish can refer to performance of a judgment or some legal or contractual provision or to foreclosure on a mortage or some other guarantee or security.

Depending on context, you may find in English:

- [enforcement proceedings](https://www.translegal.com/legal-english-dictionary/enforcement-proceedings)
- [foreclosure proceedings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreclosure)